# calling the same function multiple times with different arguments

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

when I'm calling the same function multiple times, each time with different arguments passed, I go like this:

```
(doseq [[a b c] [[arg1a arg2a arg3a] [arg1b arg2b arg3b] [...]]
  (myfunction a b c))
```

is there a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: It might help if you specify what you find inconvenient about this. What are the problem parameters? Do you have to specify each argument manually, or can you generate them somehow? Logically, if you must specify each argument manually, then there's not much room for improvement: the overhead to your current  method is about 10-20 characters, not counting white-space.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative is to use `apply`. I really don't know though if it is that much more convenient:

```
(doseq [args arg-seq]
  (apply myfunction args))
```

Comment: yes, this looks good. it's an improvement because it works for arbitrary arities.